# What Non Homebrew classes Multiclass well with Necromancy Wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, necromancy

I am trying to ask this question as non opinionated as I can.  Hard to do with non rules questions which are generally direct. So currently there is a Level 2 Variant Human Wizard of the Necromancy School with the Magic Initiate Feat.

Stats
Str 9, Dex 14, Con 16, Int 16, Wis 10, Cha 10
Cantrips: Chill Touch, Ray of Frost, Frostbite (Necromancy/Cold theme) and Magic Initiate gave me Blade Ward, Toll of the Dead (Necromancy) and 1 free casting of Healing Elixir (Alchemist theme) from new level 0 and level 1 playtest spells.

This Wizard has been built as a sort of Alchemist who is only studying Necromancy as a means of stopping, controlling and killing undead as to prevent them from inflicting harm upon the rest of the world. Themes are heavy cold/Ice element with Necromancy mixed in (there isn't much to start with...) and anything that helps play out the alchemist theme.

Taking away Stat requirements which this Wizard may not yet meet for Multiclassing, do any worthwhile AL legal MC options exist for the Necromancy Wizard that help add to, improve, or enhance its Spellcasting options or role as a backline caster? Or, as I suggested, should the Wizard stick to what it is good at and go Full Wizard?

Comment: What spells did you get with Magic Initiate?

Comment: Also, you probably need to define "worthwile". What is worthwile for you? Answers are vastly different depending on that.

Comment: It seems you forgot to describe your goal. What exactly you want to get from the multiclassing?

Comment: Sorry everyone. I hadnt obtained enough details I suppose. I am not used to asking these sort of questions for my players.

Comment: The details added haven't helped: they do not describe a singular goal that answers can be judged objectively against. The problem with the question remains: the end of your question is asking for discussion and ideas about what you should maybe do, not asking how to accomplish a specific goal. (*Without* editing it, it would be fine on a [discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449).)

Comment: @Airatome This is on hold so I can't post an answer but you might want to look into dipping 2 levels into Warlock. That will give you access to Hex which is a pretty thematic spell for a necromancer. At level 2 you will also get invocations, and if you take Devil's Sight, you can get Darkvision for your human.

Answer (score 4):

You are right that, in general, there is very little for a wizard to gain by multiclassing. Your spellcasting gets slowed down, and unless you're running a very unusual wizard, your spellcasting is the only thing you really care about. However, for wizards in general, and you in particular, there is one area that stands to improve greatly by multiclassing.

Your current AC of 13 (Mage Armor) + 2 (Dex) = 15, can, with a single fighter level (which your stats already allow you to take), be bumped up to 15 (half plate) + 2 (Dex) + 2 (shield) +1 (Defense Fighting Style) = 20. It costs you a level, and 760 gp, but for +5 AC, and one extra spell slot per day, that's not necessarily a bad trade. If you weren't casting mage armor, and were instead running around with an AC of 12, you don't get the extra spell slot per day, but your AC goes up by a whopping +8.

A popular alternative to a fighter level for this purpose is a cleric level, which can get you heavy armor proficiency and some new spells, as well as not slowing down your spell slot progression. However, your Wis is too low to multiclass into cleric, and your Str is too low to use heavy armor.

Comment: I would mention the benefits of 2 levels of Fighter (action surge)